# Is the error function and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ the same thing?

Tags: error-function

Are $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $\Phi(x)$ the same thing? It seems that the derivative $\Phi(x)$ and the density of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ are the same, but I'm not sure.

Comment: $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the CDF (cumulative distribution function) of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. They are not the same (one being a CDF and the other being a distribution), but both contain same amount of "information" to recover one from the other and vice versa.

Comment: I don't quite understand, can you use a simpler language?

Comment: Addtionally, the "error function" $\operatorname{erf}(\cdot)$ is a slight variant of $\Phi(\cdot)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of terminology. They are not the same, but they apply to the same concept.

If a random variable $X$ has the *standard normal probability distribution* $\mathcal N(0,1)$, then the *cumulative probability function* that $X$ is less than $x$ is $$\Phi(x)=P(X<x).$$

Since you are asking about the "error function", we also have the following.

If a random variable $Y$ has the *normal probability distribution* $\mathcal N(0,1/\sqrt 2)$, then the cumulative probability that $Y$ is between $-x$ and $x$ is the so called *error function* $$\operatorname{erf}(x)=P(-x<Y<x).$$

Comment: Note in the latter you are considering only $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

The following functions are essentially the same thing

- [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)
  $$
  \operatorname{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\color{red}{0}}^ze^{-t^2}\,dt\,.
  $$
- Cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution ${\cal N}(0,1)$:
  $$
  \Phi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\color{red}{-\infty}}^ze^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt\,.
  $$
- Heat kernel
  $$
  p_t(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4t\pi}}\int_{\color{red}{-\infty}}^ze^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}\,dx\,.
  $$
  Obviously,
  $$
  \boxed{\quad\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erf}\Big(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)=\Phi(z)=p_{\frac{1}{2}}(z)\,.\quad}
  $$